# Wordpress "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page." for newly-installed plugins

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, capistrano

I have a working installation of Wordpress 4.5.3, with WooCommerce 2.5 and about 20 other plugins. Recently, I installed a few new plugins using git, and when I try to access the new plugins' settings pages, for example `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=mailchimp-for-wp-top-bar`, Wordpress throws this error:

```
You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.
```

I have a development version of the same site locally, and the plugins work fine. Some people suggest that the `$table_prefix  = 'wp_';` in the `wp-config.php` file might be the problem, but my settings match the DB.

What could be causing this error on almost all new plugins that I install?

Note: the site is deployed using Capistrano.

Comment: please, install [this plugin](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) and check if your current user role has the permissions installed by that plugin (maybe some new permissions and roles have been added by that plugin), eventually you can add them

Comment: This is surely a problem of user capability in the plugin itself (or a problem of files/folder permissions (CHMOD) in that plugin files on your server)…